# Cache Manifest not working in Android Browser

Tags: android-browser, cache-manifest

Cache Manifest doesn't work in Android Browser. It works fine in Chrome on Android, Safari on iOS and all main desktop browsers (Not IE).

My index.html starts like this:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML>

  <html manifest="cache.manifest" lang="en-GB">

  <head>`

My cache.manifest starts like this:

> CACHE MANIFEST
>
> # v1.0.1 - 2013-10-23
>   # Cache manifest created by Jez D
>
> CACHE:
>   index.html
>   styles.css
>   scripts.js

As stated, this works fine on all relevant browsers except Android Native browser.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863380/cant-get-simple-html5-manifest-cache-to-work), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241796/android-browser-ignores-cache-manifest-on-mobile-device-galaxy-s3) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12128) but to no avail.

Android version is 4.2.2

What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is in the following article. At least, it did it for me.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Assuming you're using Apache as your web server, you need to make it serve your .manifest file in the correct content-type by adding the following line to your httpd.conf file.

AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest

By doing this and restarting my Apache server, it fixed the problem under Android's native browser. (v4.1.2) As you mentionned, other browsers were working fine without this line in my config file.

Hope this helps!